# entire <li> element that contains <a href> and <span> as a clickable link

Tags: css, html-lists, block, html

**[SOLVED] The answer: finally noticed that < /a > closes before the < span > tags (check initial html code in the question), and that was the cause of the problem! Thank you all for your help!! This happens when you are tired and try to change someone else's code :)** – dev101

---

I have searched, I have tried, but this one is giving me a headache. I know how to make a regular **li** element clickable as a block hyperlink, but when I put a **< span >** tag inside **li**, only the portion around **< a... >** inside the ** div ** appears as a link, not the entire **li** wrapper. Can you help?

**html code**

```
<li>
<a class="category" href="http://link...">link_title</a> <span>(some text)</span>
</li>
```

after much trial and error the only thing that was acceptable from a design point of view is just a regular hover highlight (no link functionality) like this:

**css code**

```
div.category ol li,div.category ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
div.category ol li:hover,div.category ul li:hover{
    display:inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#EEE;
}
```

No matter what I try,  elements are always breaking in new row or hags somewhere, and only part behind  is clickable inside wrapper div (or ol/ul element). Any idea?

Thanks
dev101

---

edited code to remove div.category but still doesn't work:

```
.category ul,.category ol{
    list-style: none;
    border: none;
    margin: 0px;
}
.category ul li,.category ol li{
    display:inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.category ul li:hover,.category ol li:hover{
    background-color:#EEE;
}
.category ul li a,.category ul li a:visited,.category ol li a,.category ol li a:visited{
    display:block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
/* tried to left/right align span - still breaks into new non-clickable line */
.category span{
float:left;
}
```

Comment: There's no `div.category`, but `a.category`.

Comment: Have you considered adding onclick event to the LI itself rather than having css manipulations to acieve it?

Comment: use jsfiddle to show your problem

Comment: ok, just for completness of the Q&A, this is the code I tryed (thanks Hashem Qolami for pointing that) (see edited post)

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Can you make a small sketch of what you want?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. If you want everything in the `li` to be clickable, why don't you just put the `a` as the only child of the li and put the `span` in the `a`? Apply `a {display:block}` and/or `a {white-space:nowrap}` as needed. Anyway, given your HTML, your CSS does nothing. Maybe that's part of the problem?

Comment: Sgoldy I have tried this: <li onclick="location.href='category cat_<?php echo category_id(); ?>'">
but I get 404 error page not found. Also this solution does not change the mouse into a hand pointer which is not an issue with touch screens, but might be innefective on desktops and laptops.

Comment: I want entire li as a link, but the span thing is collapsing on a side or in a new raw and that area is not clickable.

Comment: Changing the cursor when the mouse is over the link is not that hard. But that is secondary to the main problems, which are that your CSS doesn't match your HTML and that you're unclear on what your target is. If the `href` in the `li onclick` yields a 404, then the same would happen on clicking the `a`.

Comment: @Mr Lister I have edited css and posted new version in the question -- it does do something (hover changes li color) and the link is working now, but it is broken into two lines, and only top line works as a link.

Comment: I don't see where you edited the quesiton in the last half hour, but do you have other things with `class="category"` too? That isn't very clear in the question. The question only has an `a` with `class="category"`, and since it has nothing inside it, no CSS would get applied to anything. Can you make a jsFiddle with more complete HTML?

Comment: @ LinkinTED - I have found the answer and KALD was a spot on the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am somewhat confused on what you really want here...

I think I know what you are trying to get at. However, your HTML doesn't match the CSS. Where is the div with the class category?

> I am assuming what you really want is to put the span INSIDE the anchor tag, that way it will be a part of the link. You can still manipulate the appearance of the span itself if you want since it is its own element. If you DON'T want the span inside the link, then you will have to remove the span from being inline with the link, with position absolute most likely. Otherwise the span will block the anchor tag.
>
> If you want the entire LI to be clickable you can put padding on the anchor tag that will make it cover the dimensions of the li element. It also depends on where you want the text for the link to be positions, of course. So, let's say if your li element is 200x200, you want the text from the anchor tag to be on the top left; put padding like this...

```
a.category {
    padding: 0 100% 100% 0;
// percentage of 100% to cover the entire area to the right and to the bottom
}
```

Alternatively you can use JS to make the LI itself the link w/o use of anchor tag in the html, but this is probably not as efficient as just using HTML and CSS.

> Also, it is redundant in most cases to repeat attributes that are unchanged between pseudo-states. If the width and/or height does not change from the default state to the hover state, it's not necessary to put them in the hover state.

Comment: KALD said: "I am assuming what you really want is to put the span INSIDE the anchor tag, that way it will be a part of the link."
Hi, Kald! That was exactly what I was trying TO DO! And as I commented 1 minute ago, I noticed that the <span> tag was outside the <a> and that make the things break apart! Thanks for your help in any case!

Comment: great, did you try the css I've posted above?

Comment: to be honest no, but I will try it on a different project. Thing is now working and what works - should not be fixed, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

As you want to bind a click event to an `li` element without wrapping it within an anchor tag i'd suggest a simple jQuery click event. It works better with presentation and customisation of design

DEMO **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/STTaf/2/)**

```
$(function() {
    $('li').css('cursor', 'pointer')

    .click(function() {
        window.location = $('a', this).attr('href');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Vector thank you for your answer. i have played with the script a little, but could not achieve hover effect.